# req.app.post(...)create_event - is not a function - why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm using axios, node, express, and sql to make a post request to my database, but I keep getting an error that reads: "TypeError: req.app.post(...).create_event is not a function". I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

From my function that contains my axios call:

```
    handleNext = () => {
const {stepIndex} = this.state;
if (!this.state.loading) {
  this.dummyAsync(() => this.setState({
    loading: false,
    stepIndex: stepIndex + 1,
    finished: stepIndex === 3,
  }));
  if (stepIndex === 3){
    var event = {
        title: this.state.title,
        description: this.state.description,
        date: this.state.date,
        starttime: this.state.starttime,
        endtime: this.state.endtime,
        venue: this.state.venue, 
        address: this.state.address,
        city: this.state.city,
        zipcode: this.state.zipcode,
        imgUrl: this.state.imgUrl,
        perks: this.state.perks,
        category: this.state.value,
        quantofvols: this.state.quantofvols

    }

    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/event', event).then(res =>{
        console.log(res.data);

    })
```

From my Node server:

```
    app.post('/api/event', ec.createEvent);
```

From my events controller (or 'ec'):

```
   module.exports = {
createEvent: (req, res, next) => {
    let { title, description, date, starttime, endtime, venue, address, city, zipcode, imgUrl, perks, category, quantofvols } = req.body;

    req.app.post('db').create_event([req.body.title, req.body.description, req.body.date, req.body.starttime, req.body.endtime, req.body.venue, req.body.address, req.body.city, req.body.zipcode, req.body.imageurl, req.body.category, req.body.perks, req.body.quantofvols])
        .then(event => {
            console.log(req.body)
            res.status(200).send("Success")})
        .catch(() => res.status(500).send());

},
```

And from my SQL query:

```
    INSERT INTO Events (title, description, date, starttime, endtime, venue, address, city, zipcode, imageurl, category, perks, quantofvols)
    VALUES
    ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13)
```

Comment: In ec ```req.app.post('db').create_event``` check the object ```console.log(req.app.post('db'))``` what value you are getting

Comment: I think you want to use this as global function so instead of using req.app.post( 'db' ).create_event you should use app.post( 'db' ).create_event

Comment: I tried app.post('db').create_event but it still didn't work.

Comment: Which SQL library are you using? Is `create_event` something you've defined or is it provided by the library?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that it, in the events controller, it should have been

```
    req.app.get('db').create_event
```

and not

```
    req.app.post('db').create_event
```

silly me.